# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.log(ava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V

Tags: java, log4j

I am trying to do samll Camel Application but log4j related error is coming.I checked with many forums but unfortunately no use.Please help me to solve this.Thanks in advance.

gradle dependencies:

```
+--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.6
|    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6
```

log4j related dependencies:

```
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jcl-over-slf4j', version:'1.5.8'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version:'1.5.8'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version:'1.5.8'
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version:'1.2.14'
```

Exception trace:

```
INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [com.pluralsight.orderfulfillment.config.WebContextInitializer@513aec64]
SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.8 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6, 1.7]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
Jul 05, 2017 12:58:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:118)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1075)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5368)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: "eclipse"

group = 'com.pluralsight.camel'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

description = """"""

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7



repositories {

     maven { url "http://central.maven.org/maven2/" }
}
dependencies {
    compile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version:'4.0.4.RELEASE') {
            exclude(module: 'commons-logging')
    }
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aop', version:'4.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version:'4.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-tx', version:'4.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aspects', version:'4.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version:'4.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version:'4.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version:'4.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile(group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version:'1.5.2.RELEASE') {
            exclude(module: 'spring-aop')
    }
    compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version:'1.0.0.GA'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version:'4.3.1.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version:'4.3.5.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version:'4.3.5.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api', version:'1.0.0.Final'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version:'4.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jcl-over-slf4j', version:'1.5.8'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version:'1.5.8'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version:'1.5.8'
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version:'1.2.14'
    compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version:'1.7.4'
    compile group: 'cglib', name: 'cglib-nodep', version:'2.2'
    compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version:'1'
    compile group: 'postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version:'9.1-901.jdbc4'
    compile group: 'commons-dbcp', name: 'commons-dbcp', version:'1.4'
    compile group: 'jstl', name: 'jstl', version:'1.2'
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-mapper-asl', version:'1.9.9'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-jsp', version:'2.2.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-el', version:'2.2.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version:'3.3.2'
    compile group: 'net.sf.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version:'2.3'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-spring', version:'2.13.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-spring-javaconfig', version:'2.13.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-test-spring', version:'2.13.2'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version:'4.0.4.RELEASE'
    testCompile(group: 'junit', name: 'junit-dep', version:'4.10') {
exclude(module: 'hamcrest-core')
    }
    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-library', version:'1.3'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version:'1.9.0'
    compile(group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version:'3.0.1') {
       /* This dependency was originally in the Maven provided scope, but the project was not of type war.
       This behavior is not yet supported by Gradle, so this dependency has been converted to a compile dependency.
       Please review and delete this closure when resolved. */
    }
    compile(group: 'javax.servlet.jsp', name: 'jsp-api', version:'2.2') {
       /* This dependency was originally in the Maven provided scope, but the project was not of type war.
       This behavior is not yet supported by Gradle, so this dependency has been converted to a compile dependency.
       Please review and delete this closure when resolved. */
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the question: your stacktrace says `SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.8 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6, 1.7]`, it literally describes the problem. Have you look at [this link](https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch) that the exception printed for you?

Comment: Thanks @Nathan which was useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work, the api version of SLF4J and its binding version should be compatible (same version generally).

At runtime, the SLF4J binding used is the 1.5.8 but the SLF4J API loaded is the 1.6/1.7 version :

> SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.8 by your slf4j binding is not
>   compatible with [1.6, 1.7]

You probably have a transitive dependency that pulls the 1.6/1.7 API version of SLF4J.
You could also have this jar specified in the classpath used at runtime.
Check both.

To check the dependencies of your Gradle project, you could use  `gradle app:dependencies` to get the tree of dependencies of your gradle project.

Comment: Thanks for answer,So which version I have to use java 8? am getting below from gradle dependency+--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.6
|    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6

Comment: thanks which works fine after updating 1.7.6 instead 1.5.8.+++1